# React loop through map and display components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a unique situation,

in my States I don't have a regular list that I can do map and then in each iteration to display a component, for example:

```
list.map(shape => <Shape {...shape} />)
```

But I have an [Hash Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). I need to know the `key` and the `value` so I'll have the necessary information to display it as component.
So I found a nice method: `entries()` that returns an `Iterator`, but how could I iterate it in a way that I could display new components inline?

Something like that in pseudo code:

`myHashMap.entries().toList().map((key, value) => <MyComponent myKey={key} myValue={value} />)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map function basically loops and returns result of each loop as an array. So basically all you need is an array of components in the end. There are just different routes to achieve it.

Converting HashMap to an array and running a map on it is slower. Please avoid that. Below code will loop through just once.

```
function getComponents(myHashMap) {
  const comps = [];
  myHashMap.forEach((value, key) => comps.push(<MyComponent myKey={key} myValue={value} />));
  return comps;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

You guys gave great answers, but I found the simplest syntax:

```js
Array.from(myHashMap.entries()).map((entry) => {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    return (<MyComponent myKey={key} myValue={value} />);
}
```

Comment: Converting HashMap to array (this needs extra memory and time), then running map over the array....needs you to loop at least twice over the array. It is not very intuitive.

Comment: @Sandy any other solution requires additional O(|Entries|) as well tho, and why should it loop twice?

Comment: @Sandy the extra memory and time here is irrelevant unless proven otherwise. And if the hashmap is huge enough that looping twice becomes a problem, imagine how worse of a bottleneck that rendering is going to be!

Comment: @Dorki: The solution I suggested above should be O(n) with a single time loop. In your suggested solution, it loops once for Array.From function again for .map function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59172980/time-complexity-of-array-from

Comment: @Emile: Agreed for performance. But why not to avoid it if we can.

Comment: Yeah I accept that, it's really one less O(N) scan.

Answer (score 2):

You can derive an array of keys using the built-in `Map.prototype.forEach` and then use it for `.map` in your render https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

```
let myKeys = [];
myHashMap.forEach((value, key) => myKeys.push(key);

return (
  { 
    myKeys.map((item) => <MyComponent myKey={item} myValue={myHashMap.get(key)}/>) 
  }
)
```